# PHP:find day difference between two date("YmdHis") reture

Tags: php, datetime

I need to find the day difference from the `date("YmdHis")` value.let say one value is:

```
$previous_date='20101202115755';
$current_date= date("YmdHis");
$day_difference=?????
```

Now i need to find the only day difference between two values.Is their any kind heart who can help me to find the value?

Comment: If you want a nice readable difference like "1 day, five hours and 25 minutes", see my answer to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394161/php-time-calculation/4394181#4394181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert your dates to timestamps and then subtract previous_date from current_date and divide by number of seconds in a day. This is an example:

```
$day = 60*60*24;

$now = time();
$target = strtotime('2010-12-24');

$diff = round(($target - $now) / $day);
echo $diff;
```

If you want number of days in between, subtract $diff by one.

Comment: thx it's working fine.But is it can calculate the 30/31 months number difference?

Comment: Yes. Try setting `$target` to `strtotime('2011-01-01')` and you will see that it works just fine.

Comment: The number of seconds in a day is not `60*60*24`. Sometimes, it is `60*60*24 + 1`.

Answer (score 8):

For PHP >= 5.3.0:

```
$prev = DateTime::createFromFormat("YmdHis", '20101202115755');
$curr = new DateTime();
$diff = $curr->diff($prev);
echo "Difference: ".$diff->days;
```

Comment: Not working ERROR: Call to undefined method DateTime::createfromformat()

Comment: Which is why I said "php >= 5.3.0".

Comment: +1: This answer is valid and at the time it was given, riad, did not specify which version of PHP he was targeting.

Comment: yes i agree.this ans is valid but as i use different version that's why looking for another solution. thanks @gnud.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange format...

1. Parse it to get a [*UNIX timestamp*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp) with [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) and [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

   ```
   $d = strptime($previous_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S');
   $prev_ts = mktime($d['tm_hour'], $d['tm_min'], $d['tm_sec'], $d['tm_mon'] + 1, $d['tm_mday'], $d['tm_year'] + 1900);
   ```
2. Subtract the timestampes ([`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) gives the current time):

   ```
   $diff = time() - $prev_ts;
   ```
3. Divide by `60*60*24` seconds to get the difference in days:

   ```
   $diff = floor($diff / (60*60*24)); // or round(), ceil() whatever fits best
   ```

That said, if possible try to store or get the date not as `20101202115755` but as UNIX timestamp. Then you don't have to go through the conversion hassle.

[**Working DEMO**](http://codepad.org/SbFuqsXL)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$previous_date="201012021157552";
$previous_date_as_time = mktime(
  substr($previous_date, 8, 2),
  substr($previous_date, 10, 2),
  substr($previous_date, 12, 2),
  substr($previous_date, 4, 2),
  substr($previous_date, 6, 2),
  substr($previous_date, 0, 4)
);

$days_between_dates = (time() - $previous_date_as_time) / 86400;

echo $days_between_dates;
?>
```

Comment: You should add a call to either `floor()` or `round()` during the assignment to `$days_between_dates`, depending on your preference, otherwise you'll very likely get long floats back.

Comment: I know :). But I think that can be accomplished by riad like he wants it ;-).