# PHP check if 1 day passed

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP:find day difference between two date(“YmdHis”) reture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421076/phpfind-day-difference-between-two-dateymdhis-reture)

What I want to do is to get day from database, current date. And check if difference between them > 1 day:

```
$curdate= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

`$dbdate` is value stored in datetime format in db.

```
$dif=$curdate-dbdate;
```

How to check if `$dif>1 day` ??

Comment: If you move your mouse-cursor over the downvote arrow, you see a description.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the stored date is expressed in the same time zone as the server, you can convert it to a timestamp using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), and compare it to `strtotime("-1 day")`:

```
if (strtotime($dbdate) < strtotime("-1 day"))
  frobnicate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get just the day from each date.

```
$day = intval($curdate= date("d"));
```

This will get the day as an in. Do the same for the time of the data base and you get two integer representing the day. Using that you can calculate how many days have pass.

Beware that the last line should look like this:

```
$dif = abs($curdate-$dbdate);
```